# why std::string::find() can handle '\0'?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

What's the difference between the implementation of `strstr()` and `std::string::find()`?

Eg:

```
char* str = "abc\0hijk@#$%";
char* temp;
std::string str1;

for (int i=0; i <=12; i++) {
    str1.push_back(str[i]);
}

strstr(temp, "@#");// can not handle'\0' 
str1.find("@#");// success
```

Comment: One is a function for c strings  the other are for c++ strings.

Comment: The `std::string` class is a C++ class that represents a string which can contain a null character. `strstr` (a function from C, not C++) works with `char*` pointers, which point to C-style strings. Because C-style strings are null-terminated, they cannot handle embedded nulls.

Comment: One is C, one is C++, one operates on C strings (NUL terminated character arrays), one operates on C++ strings. The two are incompatible from each other. Your code also has undefined behavior as you never initialize `temp`.

Comment: `strstr(temp, "@#");// can not handle'\0'` a non initialized pointer to char can handle only few things ...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli C-Style strings are valid in C++.  All the `str*()` functions are valid in C++.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews never said that they aren't.

Comment: @Marco You did, when you claimed a dichotomy between one being C and the other being C++. One is C, _both_ are C++.

Comment: @DejaVu Provide at least a compiled minimal program without undefined behavior.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings touché.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings The term "C strings" (or "C-style strings") has a very specific meaning. It doesn't mean "strings in C", It means strings passed with a `char *` or `const char *` whose length is indicated by a terminating zero byte.

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow I missed the first line when I edited, sorry for that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks, but I know very well what C strings are. Did you maybe address your comment to the wrong person by mistake?

Comment: @Ivanovic Downvotes are not reserved for posts by old contributors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class is a C++ class that represents a string which can contain a null character. Its member functions, like `find`, are designed to handle those embedded nulls.

[`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) (a function from C) works with `char*` pointers, which point to C-style strings. Because C-style strings are null-terminated, they cannot handle embedded nulls. To this effect, `strstr` is documented as follows:

> **Locate substring**
> Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of str2 in str1, or a null pointer if str2 is not part of str1.
>
> *The matching process does not include the terminating null-characters, but it stops there.*

The italicized part is relevant here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: "*Almost all of its member functions handle those nulls as part of the string with no problem*" - you are implying that some of `std::string`'s methods can't handle embedded nul characters. Which ones are you thinking of?

Comment: @RemyLebeau That wording is bad; I'll make it more explicit/clear. When I was writing this I had `c_str()` in mind which returns a C-string that doesn't quite match the C++ string.

Comment: How do I know how find () handles '\0', is it useful to view the source code?

Comment: @nanofarad "*with some small issues like `c_str()` returning a C-style string that cannot represent the same characters as the C++ string*" - that is not true, either. `c_str()` (and `data()`) returns a pointer to the string's raw character data, which includes embedded nulls. Now, if you *treat* that pointer as if it were a C string, then yes, embedded nulls will cause issues. But, if you take the string's actual `size()` into account while handling that data, then the embedded nuls will not cause any issues (for instance, passing the `c_str()` pointer to a function that also takes a length).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Dropping that remark entirely since I can't think of a terse enough wording to express this accurately (and must deal with other tasks now)

Comment: @DejaVu because that is how it is designed to work. `std::string` doesn't care about the *values* of its characters. `'\0'` is a valid character to `std::string`, and `find()` handles it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[strstr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) in C/C++

> This function takes two strings s1 and s2 as an argument and finds the
>   first occurrence of the sub-string s2 in the string s1. The process of
>   matching does not include the terminating null-characters(‘\0’), but
>   function stops there.

but the [std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

> Searches the string for the first occurrence of the sequence specified
>   by its arguments. When pos is specified, the search only includes
>   characters at or after position pos, ignoring any possible occurrences
>   that include characters before pos.